# Configure android application created by angularjs and phonegap using variables

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

So I have an angular application and I've created a hybrid android application using PhoneGap. But currently, I have one issue -

In the angular code, there are many places in the `service` and `controller` files where API calls are made. Now, the path of the server from where the API call is made needs to be configurable i.e making a change to a variable in a single file should reflect the change in all angular files. I'm have an idea of using a variable that could be used like - Say the variable is `configurableVar`; then the variable could be used as such - `http://$rootScope.configurableVar/api/call` *(I'm not sure whether a `rootScope` variable could be used with PhoneGap)*

Currently the API call is as such - `http://serverpath:port/api/call` but this serverpath is hard-coded in each controller and service files.

Also, could the **config.xml** file be used in this case? If yes, then how could I use the variable created in the config.xml in the angular files?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, I wanted to separate variable values from production/development environment.

Instead of use $rootScope.configurableVar, you should use [angular constants](http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/constants/). First update your API url references with an angular constant.

Then you can generate the constants file using [gulp-ng-config](https://github.com/ajwhite/gulp-ng-config).

For example, lets say you have a config.json file:

```
{
  "local": {
    "EnvironmentConfig": {
      "api": "http://localhost/"
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "EnvironmentConfig": {
      "api": "https://api.production.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the plugin is simple as:

```
gulpNgConfig('myApp.config', {
  environment: 'production'
})
```

And this will generate the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
.constant('EnvironmentConfig', {"api": "https://api.production.com/"});
```

So, to use this with gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpNgConfig = require('gulp-ng-config');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('config:production', function(){
  // this will generate a www/js/config.js file with production values
  gulp.src('config.json')
    .pipe(gulpNgConfig('myApp.config', { environment: 'production' }))
    .pipe(rename('config.js')) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js'))
})
```

To generate angular constants, in terminal just use the following:

```
gulp config:production
```

And to use the constants in your angular.js application just:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('myController', ['EnvironmentConfig', '$http', function(EnvironmentConfig, $http){
  $http.get(EnvironmentConfig.url + '/path');
}])
```